# Firebase : Get Facebook Photo Url [ Android ]

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-android-sdk

Im using Facebook Authentication with Firebase and I'm trying to get the Photo Url from the authenticated user. I've tried using the following method:

```
String photoUrl = firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
```

And this method :

```
String photoUrl = firebaseUser.getProviderData().get(0).getPhotoUrl().toString();
```

They both return a url in the format : https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p100x100/1230538156_10205381561684678_351630538156623_n.jpg

When I try to access this url, I get the following message:

"Access to scontent.xx.fbcdn.net was denied"

As an alternative, I have tried getting the user's facebook id so I can request the photo using the Graph API but seems to be no way to get the facebook id. I thought the following would work:

```
firebaseUser.getProviderData().get(0).getProviderId();
```

But this returns the string "firebase" ??? ...umm what?

My full method:

```
private void firebaseAuthWithFacebook(AccessToken token) {

        showProgressDialog("Signing in with Facebook","Signing in with Facebook");


        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                            if (user != null) {
                                addNewUserFacebook(user);
                            }

                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        hideProgressDialog();
                    }
                });
    }




private void addNewUserFacebook(FirebaseUser firebaseUser){
        String name = firebaseUser.getDisplayName();
        String email = firebaseUser.getEmail();

        /*My THREE failed methods - cue sad trombone */ 

        //String photoUrl = firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        //String photoUrl = firebaseUser.getProviderData().get(0).getPhotoUrl().toString();
        String photoUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + firebaseUser.getProviderData().get(0).getProviderId() + "/picture?type=large";

        String providerId = "Facebook";
        final String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();

        User user = new User(name, email, photoUrl, providerId);

        rootRef.child("users").child(uid).setValue(user, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                if (databaseError == null){
                    //add local user information
                    updateUser(uid);
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: To make it specific, does Google Sign in works?

Comment: Yes it does, but I am not asking about Google. But I will add that the facebook sign-up process is working ...i.e I am getting a firebase authenticated Facebook user. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same problem, I deleted all the data from the Facebook application in the configuration on the phone, no data, I tried and the problem solved, Facebook gets dizzy I think.

this method works for me

```
String photoUrl =  firebaseUser.getProviderData().get(0).getPhotoUrl().toString();
```